# Pandas - replace/remove everything after a specified string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data is formatted like this:

| product_name |
| --- |
| HP Ryzen 5 Hexa Core 5500U - (16 GB/512 GB SSD/Windows 11 Home) 15s- eq2182AU Thin and Light Laptop |
| DELL Inspiron Athlon Dual Core 3050U - (8 GB/256 GB SSD/Windows 11 Home) Inspiron 3525 Notebook |

These names are too long, and I would like to shorten them. A common theme with all rows of my data is that all the text before the first occurrence of  `- (` is what I want to preserve for the product name.

How do I remove all the text that comes after  `- (`, including  `- (` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas's [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas-dataframe-applymap) should do it:

```
import pandas as pd

def shorten(s):
    return s.split(' - (')[0]
    
df = pd.DataFrame(['abc - (123)', 'def - (456)'])
print(df)
df = df.applymap(shorten)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
             0
0  abc - (123)
1  def - (456)
     0
0  abc
1  def
```

If you want to only modify a specific column, e.g. "product_name", use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) instead:

```
import pandas as pd

def shorten(s):
    return s.split(' - (')[0]
    
df = pd.DataFrame([['abc - (123)'], ['def - (456)']], columns = ['product_name'])
print(df)
df['product_name'] = df['product_name'].apply(shorten)
print(df)
```

Comment: How do I apply this specifically to the `product_name ` column?

Comment: Use df['product_name] = df['product_name'].apply(shorten) . Updated answer to include this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`string.split(" - (")[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a pandas dataframe `df`, something like would use regex to perform the replacement for all items under `'product_name'`.

`df['product_name'] = df['product_name'].str.replace('- \(', '', regex=True)`